# Next.js 13 Typescript extend Window object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

In my Next.js 13 project, I want to extend the Window object to have a property called `gtag`

In the root folder I had this `index.d.ts` file like this

**index.d.ts**

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: any;
  export const ReactComponent: any;
  export default content;
}
```

I add the following lines to that

```
export { }

declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: any;
  export const ReactComponent: any;
  export default content;
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    gtag: any;
  }
}
```

Please note that `export {}` line as well. Now my gtag is recognizing correctly. But the build failed with this error

> Module '"*.svg"' has no exported member 'ReactComponent'. Did you mean
> to use 'import ReactComponent from "*.svg"' instead?

So the conclusion is if I need to put `export {}` to work `gtag`. Same time not have `export {}` to work svg.

How can I fix this with Next.js?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
// Declare the module for SVG files first
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: any;
  export const ReactComponent: any;
  export default content;
}

// Declare the global interface for the window object
declare global {
  interface Window {
    gtag: any;
  }
}

// Export an empty object to satisfy the export {}
export {};
```